# Angular search not filtering properly

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a list of JSON data that I need to be able to filter by typing a name in. The results should then only display those listings which have that name in the result. It is currently just hiding the other names, and still showing all of the other listings.

How can I set the filter so that when you type in an actors name, it only shows the movie listings that actor is listed in?

This is the markup used to display the listings, as well as the Angular filter code:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="movies in results | filter:genre">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="well well-sm">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 text-center">
                    <img src="" alt="poster"
                        class="img-rounded img-responsive" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-9 section-box">
                    <h2>
                        {{movies.Name}}
                    </h2>
                    <div class="row rating-desc">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>{{movies.Duration}}<span class="separator">|</span>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal"></span>{{movies.Rank}}<span class="separator">|</span>
                            <a class="bookMovie" href="http://www.fandango.com/{{movies.Name}}">Book Now!</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <p>
                        {{movies.Description}}
                    </p>
                    <p ng-repeat="actor in movies.Actors | filter:actor" >
                     <span ng-bind="actor"></span>
                    </p>
                    <hr />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**The JSON and rest of the code can be seen in this plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/ZmxaSRg9ir0qlNNtOyCd?p=preview**

Comment: Do you want to search the`movies` list and the `Actors` list too,?

Comment: @AbdelrhmanMohamed - ideally. I was first working with searching the actors list though.

Comment: you can check my answer, I filter by object and only filter actors by actor and movies as genres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you should put the actor filter in your parent ng-repeat, check below plnkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/k1JVXL0Cpxysjhn2tNx7?p=preview

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="movies in results | filter:actor | filter:genre">
```

Comment: this will filter the entire movie object's properties against the input, not limited to the actors array.

Comment: How can I set this so that when I filter for a movie, it doesn't remove the actors names from that listing?

Comment: Sorry, i made this really quick, didnt have time to put best practices. Check @Abdelrhman answer, his answer is more complete =) Altough mine works as well...

Answer (score 2):

You can filter by object like this `filter:{ Genres: genre, Actors: actor }`

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="movies in results | filter:{ Genres: genre, Actors: actor }">
```

[plnkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/dTQpcmwQhhIt14ebmFKT?p=preview)